# Can I compare the confidence interval when having small sample sizes?

Tags: confidence-interval, bootstrap, effect-size

I ran an experiment in which I calculated the biomass of 2 treatments - say A and B. Each treatment had 4 replicates. I now would like to calculate

- the 95% confidence intervals of the mean biomass of A
- the 95% confidence intervals of the mean biomass of B

To calculate the confidence intervals, I would like to do it as follows (for each treatment):

1. Subsample 3 replicates
2. Calculate mean
3. Repeat 1,000 times
4. Take as the lower bound the 0.05% lowest mean
5. Take as the upper bound the 0.95% highest mean

I have two questions:

- is the sample size too small to calculate the confidence interval? I read in the book "*Bootstrap methods: a guide for practitioners and researchers*" that you should have at least 30 replicates to calculate confidence intervals using bootstrapping reliably. This means my confidence intervals wouldn't be that reliable when looking at them individually. But would this be a problem when I'm comparing the confidence intervals of the biomass in A and B? Would their inaccuracies cancel each other out?
- is it an acceptable practice to choose a bootstrapping subsample that is the number of treatments - 1 when you have a small sample size?
- from these means I will want to calculate some effect sizes using the log response ratio. Is there anything I should consider further?

Comment: Note that your procedure would return CI's at the 90% level.

Comment: Oh true! Good catch, I didn't notice it. It's the first time I code my own bootstrapping.

Comment: Note also that the bootstrap resamples the complete data, rather than a subsample (and this addresses your 2nd question)

Comment: If you are trying to do bootstrapping, then you should sample the 4 replicates *with replacement*. In fact, there are only 256 (4^4) possible ways of doing this, so one could construct the complete bootstrap distribution without random sampling.